# How to use SSIS package in C# application without installation SSIS on Server, is it possible?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis

I have few questions about the capability of SSIS package.
I want to create an SSIS package to import data from Excel to Sql server conditioned Connectoin manager needs to be dynamic i.e. should be set programatically using C#.
Is it possible ?

Also if I am integrating this package to be executed via web page when user clicks on button then Do I need to have SSIS installed on Sql server or adding reference to the needed DLL's will work out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. You can use a variable which stores your connections string, and assign this variable to the appropriate Connection Manager's Connection string property. You can launch the package programmatically from C# code.

You can read about how to do this in these articles: [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms403355.aspx) or [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/michen/archive/2007/03/22/running-ssis-package-programmatically.aspx).

Your second question: no, it is not enough to add a dll. You need Intergration Services part of the SQL server installed.

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to run SSIS package without installing Integration Services in production environment. You need a licensed version of SQL Server to install and run Integration Services for your production environment.

You can build packages and run it freely using Business Intelligence Development Studio (BIDS) that is built upon Visual Studio Shell. However, BIDS should not be used in production environment.

@luviktor has provided better option about how to change the connection string dynamically.